# What is the single-particle Hilbert space in the Fock space of QFT?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, hilbert-space, mathematical-physics, poincare-symmetry

In Quantum field theory, the fields are operator-valued functions of spacetime. So for a scalar (spin $0$) field $$\psi:  \mathbb{R}^{3,1} \rightarrow O(F),$$ where $O(F)$ is the space of operators on the Hilbert space $F$, which is the Fock space. The Fock space is is the direct sum of tensor products of copies of a single-particle Hilbert space $H$, so $$F(H) = \mathbb{C}~\oplus ~ H ~\oplus~(H~\otimes_s~H)~\oplus~(H~\otimes_s~H~\otimes_s~H)~\oplus~...$$
where $\otimes_s$ is the symmetrised tensor product since the field is a boson field. I understand that the creation operator $a_p^\dagger$ acting for example on the vacuum $$| 0 \rangle  = | vac \rangle ~\oplus~0~\oplus~0~\oplus~0~\oplus~...$$ gives a state $$a_p^\dagger~|0\rangle=|\psi_{p,1}\rangle = 0~\oplus~|p\rangle~\oplus~0~\oplus~0~\oplus~...$$

My Question now is, what's the one-particle Hilbert space $H$ exactly?

Is it just $H = L^2(\mathbb{R^3})$ as for the wave function in ordinary quantum mechanics?

Whats the representation of the definite momentum state $|p\rangle$ in $H$, if $H = L^2(\mathbb{R^3})$, would it just be $\varphi(x) = e^{ipx}$? (ignoring constants and rigged Hilbert space here).

What would be the unitary representation of the proper orthochronous Poincaré group $\mathcal{P}^\uparrow_+$ in the Fock space $F$?

Comment: "The space $F_n$ of the states of the systems of $n$ identical bosons (fermions) is a Hilbert space of square-integrable functions of $n$ variables $ψ(ξ_1 , . . . , ξ_n)$ that are symmetric (antisymmetric) with respect to the variables $(ξ_1 , . . . , ξ_n)$ (here, $ξ_i ∈ X$, where $X$ is a measure space). To emphasize that we are dealing with bosons, we use the notation $F_n^s$ for the space $F_n$ and in the case of fermions, we use the notation $F_n^a$ . The space $L^2(X_n) = L^2(X × · · · × X)$ will be denoted by $B_n$. The spaces $F_n^s$ and $F_n^a$ are subspaces of this space."

Comment: This is what is written in Schwarz _Mathematical Foundations of Quantum Field Theory_, p. 24.

Comment: I think you can take any (complex, infinite-dimensional, separable) Hilbert space. Usually one works with $L^2(\mathbb R^3,\mathrm dp)$ or  $L^2(\mathbb R^3,\mathrm dp/2E(p))$.